# Section header offset to fix it below fixed searchBar in TableView?

Tags: ios, tableview, offset

I´ve managed to fix the searchBar on the top of a TableView. But now i need to let the section headers stop below the searchBar (which is part of the tableHeaderView). I´ve subclassed the UITableView like that:

```
#import "CustomTableView.h"

@implementation CustomTableView

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect rect = self.tableHeaderView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = MAX(0, self.contentOffset.y);
    self.tableHeaderView.frame = rect;
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.tableHeaderView];
}

@end
```

I tried to keep the section headers below with this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0)
    {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44+scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    NSLog(@"offset: %f", scrollView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

I tried to put an offset with insets on the tableView. But it produces a gap on top when pulling the tableView down to the end. And trying to remove them while user is still dragging doesn´t make sense (like in my attempt).

I know i could go with an UIView and put there a searchBar on the top and place a UITableView below that but i would have to change a lot of code as i started to build this view based on the TableViewController.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: It wouldn't take long at all to move it over to a UIViewController. You can keep 99% of the code it's really just a matter of setting up the IB stuff. And it would be much easier than trying to get all hacky like this.

Comment: Probably you´re right. I´ll try that tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: not a problem, glad I could help.